# Duplicate rows returned with worklog entries. I just need the latest entry

Tags: sql, mysql, logging, duplicates, row

I made this query which works.  The issue is it displays rows for every worklog.  I only need the latest worklog for each incident.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Incident Number` AS Incident_Number,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Status` AS Status,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Priority` AS Priority,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Assigned Group` AS Assigned_Group,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Assignee` AS Assignee,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Submit Date` AS Submit_Date,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Last Modified Date` AS Last_Modified_Date,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Description` AS Description,
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Submitter` AS Submitter,
`HPD:Search-Worklog`.`Worklog Description` AS Worklog_Description,
`HPD:Search-Worklog`.`Work Log ID` AS Work_Log_ID
FROM
`HPD:Help Desk` 
INNER JOIN `HPD:Search-Worklog` on (`HPD:Search-Worklog`.`InstanceId` = `HPD:Help Desk`.`InstanceId`)
WHERE 
(`HPD:Help Desk`.`Status` in ('Assigned','Pending','In Progress')
And `HPD:Help Desk`.`Submit Date` >= $__from/1000 and `HPD:Help Desk`.`Submit Date` <= $__to/1000)
ORDER BY
`HPD:Help Desk`.`Submit Date` ASC
LIMIT 20
```

I've tried the HPD:Help Desk, HPD:Worklog, and HPD:Search-Worklog forms.  I've also tried using the CASE statement to only display the latest/max work log id for each incident to no luck.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious/simple.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (If it's MySQL, which version?)

Comment: btw: using case within a select statement is actually a `case expression` - terminology matters

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a recent version of MySQL(or variant of) that supports window function, a very effective way to get "the most recent" of something is to use `row_number() over()`. Within the over clause use `partition by` to control what will trigger a reset of row numbering and use the `order by` to control which row within the partition that gets the row number 1. Now to get "the most recent" requires some column in the worklog table that enables this - I have assumed a timestamp column (`worklog_entry_date` exists in that table (`worklog_entry_date`), you will need to substitute the actual column(s) that determine "most recent". Nest the current query one layer so that you can then filter for when row numbers are 1 - these will then be "the most recent" rows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
          h.`Incident Number` AS Incident_Number
        , h.`Status` AS STATUS
        , h.`Priority` AS Priority
        , h.`Assigned Group` AS Assigned_Group
        , h.`Assignee` AS Assignee
        , h.`Submit Date` AS Submit_Date
        , h.`Last Modified Date` AS Last_Modified_Date
        , h.`Description` AS Description
        , h.`Submitter` AS Submitter
        , w.`Worklog Description` AS Worklog_Description
        , w.`Work Log ID` AS Work_Log_ID
        , row_number() over(partition by h.`Incident Number`
                            order by w.worklog_entry_date DESC) as rn
    FROM `HPD: HELP Desk` h
    INNER JOIN `HPD: Search - Worklog` w ON w.`InstanceId` = h.`InstanceId`
    WHERE h.`Status` IN ('Assigned', 'Pending', 'In Progress')
        AND h.`Submit Date` >= $_ _from / 1000
        AND h.`Submit Date` <= $_ _to / 1000
    ) d
WHERE d.rn = 1
ORDER BY
      d.`Submit Date` ASC 
LIMIT 20
```

nb: you should not need `select distinct` when row numbering is in place - and in general avoid this when you can. Also, do yourself a favour and start using table aliases to simplify your code.